# What resources or software should my computer have to play M2TS file without delays?

Tags: media-player, codec, m2ts

My computer's configuration is:

```
Intel Core i5-2500 3.30GHz
RAM 8 GB
NVIDIA GeForce GTX 460 1GB
HDD 1GB 7200 
Sound Blaster X-Fi Xtreme Audio
Monitor with 1920x1200 resolution

Windows 7 Ultimate (64bit)
```

I tried to view m2ts file from iso or from hdd (it does not matter). Any way my [GOM player](http://www.gomlab.com/eng/) playes video with "jerky". Could someone recommend any software or just any solution how to start playing video without problem on this hardware.

Comment: Is this a new installation without any unecessary software?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current setup should be more than fast enough. The first thing I would try is installing VLC from http://www.videolan.org. VLC includes its own codecs and it's quite fast.

The second thing I would try if that does not work is to convert the m2ts file to an easier-to-play format using either ffmpeg or mencoder. My own main PC is much slower than yours, so I convert all HD video files to AVI at a lower resolution before playing.

Comment: +1 for VLC. I use both VLC and K-Lite Codec Pack (you can also try CCCP), but VLC will play **anything** the other two can't.  Also, VLC (as CarlF mentioned) uses it's own self-contained codecs, so it won't impact any of the pre-installed DirectShow codecs on the machine (it's about as close to a "portable" media player codec pack as you can get).